# Javascript/CSS: Change button to a text field on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that I need to change into a text field (Ideally expand into it using an animation) when clicked. Right now I have my button and text field beside each other on the page:

```
echo '<form id= "changePassForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';  
echo '<div class="changePass">Change Password</div>';
echo '<div class="changePassBtn" method="post"></div>';
echo '<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">';
echo '</form>';
```

I can set the password to hidden at start but I need to know how to make the changePass button "become" or expand into the password text field either using CSS or javascript. 
I'm new to javascript and am unsure how to accomplish this on button click.

How can I change a button to a text field on click? I need to be able to change back to the button afterwards

I'm getting this:
[image]

With this:

```
echo '<form id="changePassForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="changePass">
    <div class="changePassBtn">Change Password</div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>';
```

And

```
    .wrapper {
        background: #50a3a2;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow: scroll;
        z-index: -1;
        text-align: center;
    }
.changePass {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
}

.changePass input {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.changePass, .changePassBtn {
  background: #2d89ef;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2b5797;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 120px;
}

.changePass, .changePassBtn:hover {
  background: #2b5797;
  border-top: 2px solid #2d89ef;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Even when I take it out of the wrapper entirely your colors do not come through. Why is this happening?

Comment: Usually this is done by hiding the button once clicked and making a default-hidden text field visible.  Once you want to change back, hide the text field again and display the button.

Comment: What @IrkenInvader said. I don't think it's good practice to be changing the type of an input form dynamically. If you want the animation to look pretty, you could put both the button and text field in a div, and have the div itself expand while hiding the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both your button and input field in the same div and then overlap them using the positioning trick with `relative` and `absolute`. Then use JQuery to make it look pretty when hiding the elements.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wpbL3kjx/9/

```js
//Shows Input Box When Focussed
$(".changePassBtn").click(function() {
  var neww = $(".changePass input").css("width");
  $(this).animate({
    width: neww
  }, 300, function() {
    $(".changePass input").fadeIn(300, function() {
      $(".changePassBtn").hide();
    }).focus();
  });
});

//Shows Button When Unfocussed
$(".changePass input").blur(function() {
  $(".changePassBtn").css("width", "auto");
  var neww = $(".changePassBtn").css("width");
  $(this).animate({
    width: neww
  }, 300, function() {
    $(".changePassBtn").show(0, function() {
      $(".changePass input").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(".changePass input").css("width", "auto");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.changePass {
  position: relative;
}
.changePass input {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
}
.changePass .changePassBtn {
  background: #2d89ef;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2b5797;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.changePass .changePassBtn:hover {
  background: #2b5797;
  border-top: 2px solid #2d89ef;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="changePassForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="changePass">
    <div class="changePassBtn">Change Password</div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If anyone wants to clean this up and edit it feel free. I just wanted to get a working example for him relatively quickly. The code probably isn't optimized, but it's what made it run the smoothest for me.

Comment: Great, thanks! With the animation, it expands to the right. I'm not versed in jquery but how would you make it grow from the center out?

Comment: If you set an absolute width for the div and input box, you can also align the button so it is in the center of the div.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wpbL3kjx/12/, the javascript and css were updated to assume you have a set width for the button and input.

Comment: Sorry - I just tried to implement this and I've copied your code verbatim but there's something off - the query isn't running although it's linked and I've copied the CSS too. I posted a screenshot of what I'm getting. The only CSS the buttons should be inheriting is from the .wrapper above

Answer (score 1):

You can `echo` both the button and text field, and make sure the field is hidden by default - `echo '<div id="button" style="display:hidden"></div>';`. Then, with javascript hide the button and show the text field when the button is clicked.

```
button = document.getElementById('theButtonID');
field = document.getElementById('theFieldID');
button.onclick = function(){
    button.style.display = 'hidden';
    field.style.display = '';
}
```

An animation can be done by changing `field.style.width` with javascript, or using css animations.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you could do it with `.replaceWith`

For example:

**index.html**

```
<button>To input</button>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text"/>')
    });
});
```

result: https://jsfiddle.net/sws5m4cc/

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggest, some jquery can do this pretty simply, but can also be done via javascript.  I went the jquery route playing with the visibility in this jsfiddle:

js

```
$('button').on("click",function(){
    $('.hideable').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$('input').on("blur", function(){
    $('.hideable').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

css:

```
.hideable{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility .35s, opacity .5s linear;
}

.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

the fiddle includes both javascript method and jquery methods
https://jsfiddle.net/youkgd2q/4/

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to have the behavior(functionality) separated from the structure of the page (html document) and the  presentation (css/style).

I would create some classes (show/hide) in css and use that classes to make certain changes in the DOM and this way i could find easier eventual bugs.

Another way would be to use a library like jQuery and make use of their functions, for example [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="username"/>
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password"/>

<input type="text" id="other" class="hideThis" name="other" placeholder="please fill this too.."/>
<button id="btn" class="showThis">submit</button>
```

---

```
.hideThis {
    display: none;
}

.showThis {
  display: block;
}
```

---

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = function(){
    button.className = "hideThis";
    document.getElementById('other').className = 'showThis';
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bogdan_vq/Lrf76dsb/1/)

Cheers!